# Representation on a splitting field and base change

Tags: representation-theory

I don't understand the following proposition in ''introductory course on l-adic sheaves and their ramification theory on curves'' by Kindler and Rülling (see http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/users/kindler/documents/madrid.pdf)

Proposition 4.19. Let $G$ be a finite group and $E$ a field. If $E$ is a splitting field (e.g. algebraically closed), then every irreducible representation of $G$ on $E$ comes via base change from a finite extension $E_0$ of the prime field.

Let $V$ a finite dimensional irreducible $E$-representation of $G$.
Let $\mathbf{F}$ the prime field of $E$.
Does it mean that there exists an finite extension $E_0$ of $\mathbf{F}$ and an $E_{0}$-representation $W$ of $G$ such that
  $$ V \simeq W \otimes_{E_{0}} E? $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: The question was a question that can be answered with yes or no. So this does answer the question. It might not have been a good answer though, but you, as a reviewer, should really read the question first.

Comment: This answer was deleted from review, with stock comment "This does not provide an answer to the question." The question asked whether the OP's interpretation of a proposition was correct, and their statement of their suggested interpretation was clear, precise and correct. So my answer, although short, gives exactly the information that I thought the OP wanted.

Comment: Summoned here to rule on a flag. I am letting this answer stay. Possibly not the greatest of questions. But I cannot think of anything to add. An example for the purposes of illustrating this theorem (like one involving a cyclic group) will likely fail to convey many subtleties. Also, Jeremy knows this stuff better than I do.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, Jyrki. I'm really not trying to be "clever" or awkward here. My interpretation of the question was that the OP wasn't asking for help with the proof, just help with understanding the statement. It seems a perfectly reasonable question. They gave better "context" than many MSE questions by proposing a carefully thought out and carefully written suggestion of what they thought the statement might mean. As it happens, they were absolutely correct, and so I can't really think of a useful way of expanding my answer of, basically, "Yes, you're right,"

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't understand the theorem but I wrote something anyway below (after seing OP's [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344679/every-irreducible-representation-comes-via-base-change-from-a-finite-extension-o)). Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is unclear to me. Let $G$ be the cyclic group with $3$ elements $1,\sigma,\sigma^2$.  Then there is the representation $$\rho : G \to GL_1(\mathbf{F}_{5}(\zeta_3)), \qquad\rho(\sigma^k) = \zeta_3^k$$ 
(where $\mathbf{F}_{5}(\zeta_3) =\mathbf{F}_{5^2}$)

which lifts to a representation $$\tilde{\rho} :G \to GL_2(\mathbf{F}_{5}),\qquad \tilde{\rho}(\sigma^k) = \scriptstyle \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

($\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$  is the companion matrix of $1+x+x^2$ the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_3$)

That's the kind of things you can get from the tensor product. Note $\tilde{\rho} : G \to GL_2(\mathbf{F}_{5})$ is irreducible, and it becomes reducible when seen as a representation $G \to GL_2(\overline{\mathbf{F}_{5}})$. That's why it makes sense to look at $E$ algebraically closed.